# Subversion : unable to update the repository (RapidSVN Linux SVN GUI Tool)

Tags: linux, svn, rapidsvn

I'm trying to update my new repository which is stored in cloud **assembla** .com .

Error: Error while updating filelist (sqlite[55]:cannot open savepoint - SQL statements in progress)
Error: Error while performing action: Commit failed (details follow):
Sqlite[S1]: unknown error

[image: Error Image]

When I'm trying to commit again, It is saying like already Locked

when I try to unlock by right click the repo --> unlock command

Execute: Unlock
Error: Error while performing action: Working copy  locked.
 is already locked.
Ready

Sorry: If you feel this question is irrelevant. I'm using subversion first time.

Answer (score 0):

Unlock the main branch repository.
Update and commit each individual folder's.

I'm not sure might be RapidVPN has some issues with dealing with lot of files in a multiple folder's.